# image does not stay in right position

Tags: html, css, image

I want something like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                   |
| LOGO                           Search_box... ITEM_1 ITEM_2 ITEM_3 |
|                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The `LOGO` is an image. `Search_box` is an `input text` and `ITEM_X` an orizontally list item.

I tried this, but the logo doesn't stay where I want: https://jsfiddle.net/mna4de2n/

**Note**: I did not implement the `input text` yet.

CSS:

```
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5vw;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header li {
   display: inline;
}

header li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #262626;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.5vh 0.5vw;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header .left {
    padding-left: 15%;
    float: left;
}

header .right {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 25%;
}

header img {
  width: 10%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="left">
      <li><img src="http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/YouTube-logo-2017-logotype.png"></li>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Matcha</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: you shouldn't have `<li>` inside `<div>`. [Here you go.](https://jsfiddle.net/mna4de2n/3/)

Comment: Because `li` stands for `list item`. `li` should go inside `ol` or `ul`. [See this](https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/tag_li.asp).

Comment: because li is a sub element of ul or ol you need them.

Comment: It's great that you have a jsfiddle but you also add the code in a code block/snippet in the question itself since the fiddle could break at some point.

Comment: There is a typo in the CSS change that you made, @alex. See the .left class. It says "disaply" instead of "display." Display should just be removed since it has no effect here.

Comment: @alex, thank you. But, what about vertically align of the logo?

Comment: Yeah, thank you @Trioj. [Here is new link](https://jsfiddle.net/mna4de2n/9/).

Comment: @Alex to vertically align [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use flexbox?

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header img {
  width: 50%;
}

header .left {
  width: 30%;
}

header .right {
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0.5vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

header li a {
  color: #262626;
  padding: 0.5vh 0.5vw;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header input {
  height: 30px;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/YouTube-logo-2017-logotype.png">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <input type="search">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Matcha</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<header>

<div class="right">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Matcha</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>



<div class=""> <!-- You do not need this class here, now all you need to do is work on centering your menu. -->
 <img src="http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/YouTube-logo-2017-logotype.png">
</div>
```

I moved your logo after the right floated menu. and removed the li tag from the logo and the class for that div (float left is not needed.).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the image width to pixels, instead of `percentage`, this is making the parent of the image to take the full width of the header. Which is causing the issue. Also removing the `li` tag wrapping the image, since it is of no use.

**Before:**

```
header img {
  width: 10%;
}

<div class="left">
    <li><img src="http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/YouTube-logo-2017-logotype.png"></li>
</div>
```

**After:**

```
header img {
  width: 100px;
}

<div class="left">
    <img src="http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/YouTube-logo-2017-logotype.png">
</div>
```

***Note: Please view the demo in full screen to see the change.***

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header li {
  display: inline;
}

header li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5vh 0.5vw;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header .left {
  padding-left: 15%;
  float: left;
}

header .right {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 25%;
}

header img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="left">
      <img src="http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/YouTube-logo-2017-logotype.png">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Matcha</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have kept the `li` under ul, instead of div and changed the image size to pixels.

```
<div class="left">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <img src="http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/YouTube-logo-2017-logotype.png">
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left ul{
  padding:0;
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.5vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header li {
  display: inline;
}

header li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #262626;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3vh 0.5vw;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header .left {
  padding-left: 15%;
  float: left;
}

header .right {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 25%;
}

header img {
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="left">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img src="http://logok.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/YouTube-logo-2017-logotype.png">
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Matcha</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```